# How to Define a Custom Object Mapper In Spring Boot Without Impacting Default Object Mapper of Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, objectmapper

Consider a Spring Boot Application:

**Model Class 1**

```
package com.example.demo.model;

public class BigClass {

  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  // Getters Setters are trimmed for brevity
}
```

**Model Class 2**

```
package com.example.demo;

public class BigClass {

  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  private Boolean isPresent;
  // Getters Setters are trimmed for brevity 
}
```

**Rest Controller**

I am trying to map one "BigClass" object containing extra member variables to another "BigClass" object containing lesser number of member variables.

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

  @Autowired
  private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @GetMapping("/hello")
  public void sayHello() {
    BigClass bg = new BigClass();
    bg.setId(1234);
    bg.setName("Demo");
    bg.setIsPresent(true);
    com.example.demo.model.BigClass bigClass =
        objectMapper.convertValue(bg, com.example.demo.model.BigClass.class);

  }
}
```

This Code runs perfectly fine because the Spring Boot default Object Mapper has specification of "DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES : disabled"

---

**But When I alter the Main class and add a custom Object Mapper as below**

**Main Class**

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class DemoApplication {

      @Bean("myCustomBean")
      public ObjectMapper customObjectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper();
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
      }

  }
```

The above Rest Controller code stops working giving below error :

```
curl "localhost:8081/hello"


 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "isPresent" (class com.example.demo.model.BigClass), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "id", "name"])
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.example.demo.model.BigClass["isPresent"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:61) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:840) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1206) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1592) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1570) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:294) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:3917) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:3853) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
    at com.example.demo.HelloController.sayHello(HelloController.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_242]
```

**My Questions**:

1. Why did my object mapper bean (having unique bean name) impacted the functionality of existing default spring boot Object Mapper
2. In this case, if I do not have control over legacy code using the default object mapper , what are my options to define my custom object mapper without breaking the legacy code . 
   Note :  I cannot change the legacy code in any way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Spring Jackson auto configuration uses `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` to create the default `ObjectMapper`. This means it only creates it if there isn't an existing bean of the same type. So by creating your own `ObjectMapper` bean, the Spring auto config doesn't create one.

I think you have a couple of options:

- If you need to control the behavior of the default Spring `ObjectMapper`, then you can use the `spring.jackson.*` properties to configure its behavior.
- If you really need 2 `ObjectMapper` objects with different behavior, you'll have to create them both as beans, give them unique names, and mark one as `@Primary` to control when/where they are autowired.

Comment: If I use spring.jackson.* I would only be able to add some property to existing bean. If I want my bean to NOT have the spring Boot default customizations then that won't be possible.

Comment: @Ananya You can use use `spring.jackson` settings to override just about every default options that Spring sets: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#json-properties

Comment: I understand your point. Let me re phrase my problem. Let's say I need 2 object mapper behaviours. One object mapper should not fail on unknown property (In my case this is the legacy code behaviour) and the other behaviour should be that object mapper should throw error on finding unknown property while deserialization (this is my case).    So we are taking about the same property (fail_on_unknown_property ) but different values in different use cases.

Comment: @Ananya That makes sense. I would follow the 2nd suggestion I made, which is to manage both `ObjectMapper`s yourself as beans, and then just programmatically configure them as needed. You can give them both unique names, and then autowire by name where needed. You can also mark one with `@Primary` to make it the default for legacy code that you cannot modify (i.e. where you cannot autowire by name).

Answer (score 1):

In the readme on a project for a custom filtering configuration for jackson I described the integration of an additional ObjectMapper.

https://github.com/Antibrumm/jackson-antpathfilter/blob/master/README.md#spring-integration

It will take some more work than just declaring a bean but you  should be able to adapt the approach to define your own.

The trick is to register your own *MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter*

Answer (score 0):

When creating our own ObjectMapper bean, we need to configure its properties

```
@Bean("myCustomBean")
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    return new ObjectMapper().setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES , 
       false);
}
```